# Gridview Rowcommand Datakey gives index out of range error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowcommand, datakey

I have added a button named reserve to my gridview, and when I click it I want do some modification on the gridview, however it gives index out of range error. Below is rowCommand method:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            welcomeUser.InnerText = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
        }            
    }
```

Below is my gridview columns:

```
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BookName" HeaderText="BookName" 
                SortExpression="BookName" />
              <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Reserve" CommandName="Reverse" />
        </Columns>
```

Comment: Do you set DataKeyNames on your gridview?

Comment: this solved the problem, please write it as an answer and I will accept it, do I need datakeys to make modifications on the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the DataKeyNames if you wish to use DataKey[index] expression
[See MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)